# Adding Velocity to Objects Position Returns NaN

Tags: javascript, class, canvas, physics

I am trying to make my canvas arcs (dog objects) follow the mouse cursor.

When I console.log the objects position or velocity it returns Vector{ x: NaN, y: NaN}

However, if I comment out the velocity assignment to the position, then the code seems to work as expected (without the object moving towards the mouse)

Why is this?

I'm not sure what to try to get this working?

```
// MAIN.JS

import Vector from './vector.js';
import Dog from './dog.js';

window.onload = function() {

    let mouse = new Vector();

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=> {
        mouse.setXY(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    });

    const   CANVAS = document.getElementById(`dogyard`),
            CANVAS_CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext(`2d`),
            CANVAS_WIDTH = 800,
            CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;

    CANVAS.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
    CANVAS.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

    let dogs = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            dogs[i] = new Dog();
            dogs[i].id = i;
            dogs[i].color = `#A66253`;
            dogs[i].position = new Vector(Math.floor(Math.random() * CANVAS_WIDTH), Math.floor(Math.random() * CANVAS_HEIGHT));
            dogs[i].velocity = new Vector(0, 0);
            dogs[i].acceleration = new Vector(0, 0);
    }

    function frames(){

        // Clear the canvas/frame
        CANVAS_CONTEXT.clearRect(0,0,CANVAS.width,CANVAS.height);

        dogs.forEach( (dog, index, array) => {
            // Draw the dog
            CANVAS_CONTEXT.beginPath();
            CANVAS_CONTEXT.fillStyle = dog.color;
            CANVAS_CONTEXT.arc(dog.position.x,dog.position.y, 10,0, Math.PI*2);
            CANVAS_CONTEXT.fill();
            CANVAS_CONTEXT.closePath();

            //Add the dog number
            CANVAS_CONTEXT.font = "12px Arial";
            CANVAS_CONTEXT.fillStyle = `#081E29`;
            CANVAS_CONTEXT.fillText(index, dog.position.x , dog.position.y);

            // Set Velocity to the current mouse position    
            dog.velocity.setVector(mouse);
            //Subtract the mouse position from the dogs current position to determine distance
            dog.velocity.sub(dog.position);
            // Decrease the velocity by 20%    
            dog.velocity.mult(0.2);  
            // add the velocity to the dogs position
            dog.position.add(dog.velocity);
        })

        requestAnimationFrame(frames);
    }

    frames();

}
```

```
// VECTOR.JS
export default class Vector{

    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    setXY(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    setVector(vector){
        this.x = vector.x;
        this.y = vector.y;
    }

    add(vector){
        this.x += vector.x;
        this.y += vector.y;
    }

    sub(vector){
        this.x -= vector.x;
        this.y -= vector.y;
    }

    mult(number){
        this.x *= number;
        this.y *= number;
    }

}
```

```
// DOG.JS

export default class Dog {

    constructor(){
        this.id;
        this.position;
        this.velocity;
        this.acceleration;
        this.color;
    }
}
```

Console.log returns NaN

Comment: "Console.log returns NaN" - there is no console.log anywhere in your code. With what arguments are you calling it and when?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I must have removed the console.log statement but this was positioned at the end of the forEach loop, right after the "dog.position.add(dog.velocity);" line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not initialize the coordinates of your mouse vector, so they are `undefined`. Replace it with `var mouse = new Vector(0, 0);`. Arithmetic operations on undefined happen to result in NaNs.